# Parallel, matrix-free estimate of the trace

Tags: linear-algebra, parallel-computing, matrix-free

What would be the best way to estimate the trace of a **large**, distributed matrix, if one only know its action on a vector throug a parallel "matvec" routine?

In the application I am interested in, the matvec routine comes from the discretization of a PDE. In most cases, I cannot modify this routine.

I do not need machine precision and would be satisfied with moderate accuracy.

Comment: Would applying the operator the identity matrix work?

Comment: Yes, but it would require O(n) matvec for a n by n matrix which I fear is intractable.

Comment: I was thinking about n matvec operations that can be parallelized. But if that's "intractable" for you, I think that would go into the question.

Comment: How about stochastic/heuristic methods? For example, Hutchinson's trick; an accessible write up at the link: http://blog.shakirm.com/2015/09/machine-learning-trick-of-the-day-3-hutchinsons-trick/ . I don't know if that is tractable for your application though. You need to sample some number of vectors and do matvec and vecvec multiplications.

Comment: @Abdullah Ali Sivas: Thanks for the suggestion. I will consider this method. That being said, what I had in mind was a method that would directly link the matvec operation with an estimate of the trace (or any power-iteration/arnoldi like method).

Comment: Trying to answer my own question, I remembered that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. Maybe this relation could be exploited?

Comment: You can also write the trace of a matrix $A$ as $\sum_i e_i^T Ae_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th column of the identity matrix. Assuming you have an efficiently implemented action of the matvec operation ( $O(n)$ ) and the inner product is also $ O(n) $, you can compute the trace in $O(n^2)$ operations. Probably, you can further reduce the cost of the action of matvec by exploiting the sparsity of the vector to $O(n\log n)$ - i.e. $n$ times the cost of finding the collision between non-zero indices. The question you are asking is very tough. I don't know any literature about that.

Comment: @ChristineDarcoux, check this too: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04893.pdf

Comment: [This recent post by Nick Higham on Trace of a Matrix](https://nhigham.com/2023/01/24/what-is-the-trace-of-a-matrix/) is also a good source for the already mentioned Hutchinson's trick for stochastic trace estimation.

Answer (score 2):

First, for most sparse matrices you don't actually need $n$ matvecs with unit vectors to determine the diagonal entries. Rather, if you know the sparsity pattern, you can "color" the nodes in your discretization so that nodes of the same color do not couple in the matrix. As a consequence, you should be able to compute the trace of the matrix with something like ${\cal O}(10-100)$ matvecs, independent of the size of the matrix (but depending on the kind of discretization you are using).

But it might be even cheaper to use a randomized algorithm to *estimate* the trace. I don't have a reference at hand, but if you search for "randomized algorithm for estimating the trace of a matrix" you will find some.

Comment: The blog post referenced in the comments to the question does a decent job introducing randomized trace estimators and giving a couple key citations.